# Resize option not working with scale in manifest.json

Tags: quip, liveapps

So I have the "scale" option set in my `manifest.json` file, trying to follow [this](https://quip.com/dev/liveapps/1.x.x/reference/global-actions/sizing-and-resizing#quipappsenableresizing)

But anyway, when I want to use `quip.apps.enableResizing` I get this error:

```
"Resizing is only supported for elements with scale sizing."
```

If I check the `manifest.json` file in the console I can confirm that it has indeed the scale option set in the "sizing_mode" property

Am I doing something wrong? Do I have to set the "scale" option somewhere else?

Thanks!

Manifest.json

```
{
    "id": "WAjfsJkJfsP",
    "manifest_version": 1,
    "name": "Excalidraw",
    "description": "Excalidraw-Quip Integration 2",
    "version_name": "0.1.0",
    "version_number": 2,
    "sizing_mode": "scale",
    "initial_height": 500,
    "initial_width": 500,
    "toolbar_color": "orange",
    "toolbar_icon": "assets/icons/toolbar.svg",
    "thumbnail": "assets/icons/thumbnail.svg",
    "js_files": [
        "dist/app.js"
    ],
    "css_files": [
        "assets/styles.css"
    ]
}
```